# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Project1.'

Tags: swift, core-data

I am new to iOS development , can you help me anyone in bug point of you. thank you for advance.

> uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Project1.'

```
 let  context  = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
 let proj = Project() 
        let arrProj = dic.object(forKey: "Projects") as! NSArray
        for n in 0..<arrProj.count {
            let subDic = arrProj.object(at: n) as! NSDictionary
            let item = ProjectItem(dict: subDic)
            proj.arrProjs.append( item )


           let projects = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Projects", in: context)
            projects?.setValue(item.Project, forKey: "project1")
            projects?.setValue(item.Project2, forKey: "project2")
            projects?.setValue(item.ID, forKey: "projectid")
            projects?.setValue(item.radius, forKey: "radius")
            projects?.setValue(item.GeofenceType, forKey: "geo_Type")
            projects?.setValue(item.Geofence, forKey: "geofence")
            projects?.setValue(item.Coordinates, forKey: "coordinates")
        }
```

Comment: when this error is comes ?

Comment: Project have NSObject class ?

Comment: thank you for response , I am using CoreData database , while saving time  , facing this issue can you help me

Comment: @YogeshPatel Project is another class , remaining working fine     but       let projects = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Projects", in: context)  projects?.setValue(item.Project, forKey: "project1") only problem

Comment: Please check your outlets in xib or storyboard make sure all perfectly attached. please let me know ?

Comment: Please do exception break point and tell me your except code where you crash ?

Comment: okay , I will check it using break point , thank you once again

Comment: His Please check my answer as well may be it helpful for you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194172/discussion-between-user11211835-and-yogesh-patel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set values in `NSManagedObject` object, not in `NSEntityDescription` object

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Projects", in: context)
for n in 0..<arrProj.count {
    let projects = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    projects?.setValue(item.Project, forKey: "project1")
    projects?.setValue(item.Project2, forKey: "project2")
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you RajeshKumar , it's working fine , can do one more help for me , still app crashing Thread 3: signal SIGABRT ,   try context.save() while calling

Comment: please check my answer use do catch for that

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  not showing error , log , every 5 min I am sending request server , after getting server I am storing in local data base , fist time ti's working   try context.save() later showing bug. can you help me

Comment: @user11211835 Use Exception breakpoint and find where it crashes

Comment: @RajeshKumarR this error showing error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.
CoreData: error: fatal: Unable to recover from optimistic locking failure.

Comment: @user11211835 When multiple contexts try to modify the same object this error occurs.

Comment: @RajeshKumarR I have 4 tables  after getting server response it's saved in location data using same context ( let  context  = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext) , like that every 15 sec repeating this type , can please tell me how can solve this issue

Comment: @user11211835 Without seeing more details can't find the issue. Can you send the project in github or google drive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194184/discussion-between-user11211835-and-rajeshkumar-r).

Answer (score 2):

Please check this using insertobject query you can save your data in core data.

```
    let  context  = appdelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let projects = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Projects", into: context) as! Projects

    projects.project1 = item.Project
    projects.project2 = item.Project2
    or
    projects?.setValue(item.Project, forKey: "project1")
    projects?.setValue(item.Project2, forKey: "project2")
    projects?.setValue(item.ID, forKey: "projectid")
    projects?.setValue(item.radius, forKey: "radius")

    do{
    try context.save()
    }catch{
    print("error")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you  for proving solution for this problem , but this solution is not useful for me.

Comment: Welcome, my solution is working for one entity I think you have an array then rajeshkumar answer is working for you. if it single entity then you don't have to use set value you can directly get projects.project1 or project2. Thank You